# can't import a dart file

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I want to import a dart file in main.dart but android studio doesn't validate it and I tried flutter pub get and lots of another stuff

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "Invalidate Cache and Restart" in Android Studio?

Comment: Instead of typing in the import on your own, use Android Studio to do it for you. Place your mouse pointer on the error, and in the pop up select the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

To import a file you need to know what your `package` name is and the path to your file.

```
import 'package:your_package_name/myFile.dart;
```

Comment: still doesn't work